# How do you pass data to react components from express or koa without renderToString?

Tags: express, reactjs, koa

I'm unable to use React's server side rendering due to my use of client side libraries such as reqwest. I would like to pass some data to my react components, however. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is by having `api-client.js` and `api.js`.  In your browserify/webpack config you set up a client side version.  For browserify put this in your package.json (feel free to edit and add webpack).

```
"browser": {
  "./path/to/api.js": "path/to/api-client.js"
}
```

The second option is better in my opinion, but more difficult to implement.  You create an abstract representation of your API that works like this:

```
var comments = require('./api').get('comments');
comments.getById('7').then(function(comment){ ... });
comments.create({...}).then(...);
```

On the server api.js simply calls the correct functions, which all return promises.  On the client it returns a promise, makes an ajax request to the server, which calls these functions, and sends back the response, and the api client resolves/rejects its promise.

This allows the api to automatically work, and allows you to do additional things like track unfulfilled promises, and pre-populate state on the client, etc. (see react-async for example).